# Xcode instruments does not show a symbolicated trace

Tags: xcode, instruments, debug-symbols, xcode12, xcode-instruments

1. I make a configuration named `profile` the same as `debug` configuration except *Debug format information: DWARF with dSYMs*
2. I change the profile setting to `profile` configuration
3. I `profile` in Xcode and start the instruments, everything seems okay.
4. I build the app in command line using profile scheme and start the instruments and attach it.
5. It seems that the instruments already found the symbols because when I select locate symbols it shows `No new libraries to symbolicate`
   [image: No new libraries to symbolicate]

[image: UUID is right]

6. When I right click the stack, `Located dSyms` greyed out
7. When I hover the `Load dSyms`, the right dSyms path is showed
8. When I click the `Load dSyms`, nothing happened.

[image: can not symbolicate the traces]

How do I obtain the symbolicated trace? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "debug or profile scheme"? What happens if you choose Product > Profile in Xcode to profile with Instruments? What happens when you profile with the Release build configuration? If you profile with the Debug build configuration, there won't be a dSYM file to load because the Debug build configuration places the debugging symbols in the executable instead of a separate dSYM file. If you profile with the Release build configuration, there will be a dSYM to load in Step 3 of your question.

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk thank you for your answer, I updated my question. I found that profile in  Xcode is okay but build a profile ipa will cause this situation.